# How to select only two rows in tableview in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, selection, nsindexpath

I am trying to allow just two rows to be selected at a time in a table view, but it seems that I can't get a good result!

The idea is that you select one row and this sends an object to core data, then when you select a second row that sends a different thing to core data. But if you select more than two rows, it displays an alert view that says you can only select two rows.

I have tried this:

```
    NSArray *indexPathArray = [[NSArray alloc]init];
indexPathArray = [self.mainTableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];

if ( indexPathArray.count == 1) {
    NSLog(@"%@",@"we have 1 cell selected");
}
if ( indexPathArray.count == 2) {
    NSLog(@"%@",@"We have 2 cells selected!");
}
if (indexPathArray.count > 2) {
    NSLog(@"%@",@"ERROR ERROR!!!");
}
```

and I have tried many other google and stack overflow suggestions but didn't get to an end!

So how can I achieve this?

This is the method in which I have the code:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

[self setSelection:indexPath];
_profile = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

NSInteger rowNumber = 0;
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < indexPath.section; i++) {
    rowNumber += [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i];
}
rowNumber += indexPath.row;
NSLog(@"%ld",(long)rowNumber);

NSArray *indexPathArray = [[NSArray alloc]init];
indexPathArray = [self.mainTableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];

if ( indexPathArray.count == 1) {
    NSLog(@"%@",@"we have 1 cell selected");
}
if ( indexPathArray.count == 2) {
    NSLog(@"%@",@"We have 2 cells selected!");
}
if (indexPathArray.count > 2) {
    NSLog(@"%@",@"ERROR ERROR!!!");
}
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];      }
```

Comment: In what ways does your current solution not work as expected?

Comment: have you set `self.mainTableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true`?

Comment: When I select one, two, or more rows, I don't see the NSLogs I have there...

Comment: Well where _are_ your NSLogs? In other words, what method is all that code located _in_? Is your code even running? (Put an NSLog outside any condition and find out.) Is `self.mainTableView` accidentally nil? (Log it and find out.) And why in heaven's name are you initializing `indexPathArray` to an empty NSArray that you then throw away in the next line????

Comment: @pbasdf I had set self.mainTableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true and this doesn't change anything in my logs

Comment: the code is located in    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: What method is this code in? (Matt has a number of very good questions/clues.)

Comment: Which method are the above lines from?  Can you show your full didSelectRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: Is this instance properly assigned as the datasource/delegate of your table view? Can you debug the method, or just place an `NSLog` statement outside your `if` block, to see if it's *ever* being entered?

Comment: I have placed an NSLog statement outside and it works! @CraigOtis and    self.mainTableView is not nil

Comment: Well, the first thing you do in that method is to deselect the row: [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];  So it's not surprising that no rows are selected.

Comment: Yes, @pbasdf is right. If the first thing you do in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is `deselectRowAtIndexPath:`, nothing can ever stay selected. You are hitting yourself in the face and then complaining that your face is being hit!

Comment: Thank you all for your interest in this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment/Delete out the following lines in your code in method
**- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath*)indexPath**

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];  
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

And check. Your logical part should then work fine.

Explanation: TableView method **indexPathsForSelectedRows** will return the number of rows selected. And your are deselecting the selected row using this line of code:

`[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];`

Commenting/deleting only this single line of code will give you indexPathArray count as 1, because you still reload the row at the end of your method using:

```
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

The above piece of code also resets the row to be unselected as you are reloading it. So you need to comment or delete it out too.

Answer (score 1):

Delete this line:

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

from your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: thanks for your answer. it is also the solution but not explained as the checked answer!